# How to do code coverage for protractor cucumber

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I know there are lots of tools available for doing code coverage test for Mocha/Jasmine tests. But my automation framework is protractor-cucumber framework. Is there any code coverage process that can be done for this? Any tools or example can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, code coverage is to understand how much of the application code is covered in unit testing as it will have access to almost every line of application code.

Protractor is a end to end based automation testing tool. You should be thinking about functional/scenario coverage rather than code coverage.

Comment: i know the concept behind this BDD framework. But some clients did not understand and they expect to explore on that too. Sometimes in interview also they ask this question, though i explain the concept of this. So checking as any ideas or suggestion to explore for any opportunity for this.

Comment: Good luck !. :)